# Get IP adress after word "from" from a file

Tags: shell, unix

I have this file

```sh
Feb 12 13:09:36 os sshd[11320]: [ID 800047 auth.info] reprocess config line 148: ignoring RSAAuthentication option value. SSHv1 protocol is no longer supported in the server, please remove the option.
Feb 12 13:09:36 os sshd[11320]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Accepted publickey for root from 2001:778:200:4280::38 port 59677 ssh2
Feb 12 13:09:36 os sshd[11320]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Received disconnect from 2001:778:200:4280::38: 11: disconnected by user
Feb 12 13:09:38 os sshd[11196]: [ID 800047 auth.info] Keyboard-interactive (PAM) userauth failed[9] while authenticating: Authentication failed
```

and I want to get IP adresses after word "from".  So my result should be:

```sh
2001:778:200:4280::38
2001:778:200:4280::38 11
```

Is it possible to do in a shell script?

I tried to use awk:

```sh
awk -F: '{print $3}' filename
```

But I didn't get expected results.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will help, Try this,

```
sed -nr 's/.*from ([^a-z]*) .*/\1/p' file_name
```